# Drawing API for java?

Tags: java, drawing, paint

I want to be able to draw and erase on an image in java (NOT javascript). Are there any APIs for that? Bonus points if i can also draw vectors, but it's not necessary. I want to use it in my program, so I'm not looking for a stand alone program. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the graphics classes built into java?  There is a simple tutorial for this [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/DrawOnImage.html).  You really just need to get a graphics context and then you can draw whatever you like on the image.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [Processing](http://processing.org/)

Answer (score 1):

diagrams and images can be drawn using an API that can produce SVG images. I can remember two API's that are capable of this. One of them is [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and the other is [SVG Salamander](http://svgsalamander.java.net/docs/use.html).